# Get system time in VCS

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm, synopsys-vcs

Is there way to get system time in VCS/UVM ? I am looking for something similar to Perl's `localtime(time)`. Is there way to print system time for every `uvm_info` printed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `$system()` to run any system command, including system' date command.

```
initial
 begin
    $system("date");
 end
```

From [IEEE 1800](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) LRM:

> `$system` makes a call to the C function system(). The C function
>   executes the argument passed to it as if the argument was executed
>   from the terminal. `$system` can be called as either a task or a
>   function. When called as a function, it returns the return value of
>   the call to system() with data type int. If `$system` is called with no
>   string argument, the C function system() will be called with the NULL
>   string.

Also, see [here](http://verificationguild.com/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&t=3199&highlight=dpi).

Comment: $system directly returns the return value of the system call upon exit, but this value is only one to two bytes, and it usually is either 0 or an error code. The common technique for extracting the time in the simulator is to write it in a file as described in the link I posted in my answer.

Comment: In UVM is it possible to dump the wall clock times spent in each phases ?

Comment: Looks like you are talking about the time the simulator spent to run each phase. If so, the answer is yes, call  `$system` before and after each phase, write the output in a file each time and read it back. Then measure the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the version of VCS you are using. The latest version should support `$system` as defined in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 20.18.1. Assuming you are running in a UNIX based environment you can do:

```
function string get_localtime();    
  int fd;
  string localtime;
  void'($system("data > localtime")); // temp file
  fd = $fopen("localtime", "r");
  void'($fscanf(fd,"%s",localtime));
  $fclose(fd);
  void'($system("rm localtime")); // delete file
  return localtime;
endfunction
```

If your version VCS doesn't support `$system` or if your more conformable with C/C++, then use DPI (see [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 35). Create a function in C and compile it in VCS with your SystemVerilog files. In the SystemVerilog, add the `import` to allow access to your C function. Assuming your method name is my_localtime and and return time is a string, the import should look like:

```
import "DPI" function string my_localtime();
```

Comment: `localtime()` is a function of C library and returns `struct tm *` not a string. Name your own function other than `localtime`, otherwise, the simulator might call wrong function due to the shared library order dependency.

Comment: Is there a built in DPI function to get time so that I don't have to write one ?

Comment: @Greg: The linux `date` command output will be something like: `Mon Aug  7 14:00:34 PDT 2017`.  When you call `$fscanf`, you are using `%s` as the format, so it'll match a string (which is a sequence of nonwhite space characters, as per the LRM).  Since the 4th character is a white space, the `localtime` string will contain only the first 3 characters of the output (i.e., the day of the week).

Answer (score 1):

In c file wallclock.c :

```
#include <time.h>
wallclock() {
   time_t t;
   t = time(NULL);
   return (ctime(&t));
   //return time(NULL);
}
```

In SV file :

```
import "DPI-C" function string wallclock();

module try;

   //int unsigned   t;
   string t;

   initial begin
      t = wallclock();
      $write("time=%0s\n", t);
   end
endmodule
```