# how to make Modelsim run another application

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

i'm working on designing a mips processor using verilog in modelsim student version and we developed a c++ tool that converts assembly operations to machine code and save the result in .txt file so is there a way to make modelsim runs this tool when simulation starts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$system("foo");` to run any system call from system verilog, including invoking your external C++ program, like `("echo hi");` or :

```
$system("path/to/my/cpp_binary.exe arg1 arg2 arg3");
```

If you wrap it in an `initial` block, you can run it at the beginning of simulation.  [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26047469/20712)

Comment: thanks that really helped ,but is there a way to reverse this process i mean can i compile a verilog file and simulate it from a another program without opening the modelsim gui ?

Comment: modelsim has the concept of the "Command Line Interface" or CLI. If you want to compile your verilog and simulate it, you can create a Makefile to run all the compiler commands and invoke the simulation binary.  Using a Makefile or shell script is how many chip companies do a lot of CLI interaction with the HDL tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant you want to simulate an application running on your processor. To do that, you need to have a testbench that models memory with all the necessary connections to your processor. Then get your .txt file in a form that can be read by the `$readmemh()` system task. Then you load the contents of file into your memory.